# How can you delete files from an Azure WebApp using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

Suppose I want to delete all files matching `*.config.default` from an Azure WebApp.  How can I do this with PowerShell?  If I had a directory on my local machine I can do this with:

```
get-childitem -Path . -Filter *.config.default -Recurse | remove-item
```

I can currently get the webApp using the following, but I don't think this will allow me to delete any files

```
$webapp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebSiteName -ea SilentlyContinue
```

I know I can use the **KUDU** console which will allow me access to `PS D:\home\site\wwwroot>` and then I can use Powershell commands from there, but I need to be able to do this without using the console.

Answer (score 4):

Call the [Kudu VFS APIs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs).

> `DELETE /api/vfs/{path}` -- Delete the file at path.

`DELETE https://{site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/wwwroot/some.config.default`

If you really want that wildcard, call the command API instead:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#command

Of course you should never do this for an app that matters, instead you should make changes to source control and redeploy.

Comment: Mega +1 for `Of course you should never do this for an app that matters, instead you should make changes to source control and redeploy.`

Comment: The issue is that there are leftover files that can sometimes get in the way! Being able to remove them is useful prior to deployment of the new source